# Expression.Error The field 'xxxx' of the record wasn't found

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm getting the error - [Expression.Error] The field 'BUSINESS' of the record wasn't found. The preview is loading fine, yet when I filter this column on specific step to check for errors - it says so: [image]

The field is calculated in the previous queries once and it doesn't give any errors. On the 1st step - when I merge, it also doesn't show error. It happens only after I expand merged query fields (the 'BUSINESS' doesn't get merged, it's already in there). I'm ready to smash my head, because I can't see how merging can affect a field which is not being used in it at all, moreover it doesn't have any issues even before.

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(GRID_DATA, {"KeyMatch"}, ComPolicy, {"KeyMatch"}, "ComPolicy", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded ComPolicy" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "ComPolicy", {"Region", "Chain code", "REGION2", "Vendor Name", "Vendor Number", "PROMOTOOL_TYPE"}, {"ComPolicy.Region", "ComPolicy.Chain code", "ComPolicy.REGION2", "ComPolicy.Vendor Name", "ComPolicy.Vendor Number", "ComPolicy.PROMOTOOL_TYPE"}),
```

Yet i'm also concerned why does it look for 'BUSINESS' in upper-case when I've never used it in any query in upper case. It might be the issue, I don't see the roots though.

Comment: I just acknowledged it happens only "Expand" action. If I merge without expanding - there is no such error. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the text fields was formatted somehow as number. Very weird that power query didn't give me yellow post with details of error.